# Best practice for BAPI commit and rollback?

Tags: abap, bapi

I am using C# to call BAPI to communicate with SAP. I am new to this topic so I want to clarify some of the concept.

Q1: If I call BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE, should I check RETURN table or MAT_DOC field of items table to see whether it is succeed or failed?

Q2: If it is failed, need I call BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK, or just ignore it(because without BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT, data will not be saved)?

Q3: I found sometimes, even if there is error message, if I continue call BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT, the data will be saved. But sometimes it won't.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Check RETURN table. If it's OK, issue a BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT with the WAIT flag. If it's not OK, issue a BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK.

Check RETURN from BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT as there may be errors there as well (for example a database update issue).

Answer (score 0):

Ad Q1 In that particular case I'd rather check if material document number is returned in MAT_DOC. This way you don't rely on return messages. If a material document is returned, it means BAPI call was successful irrespective of messages. I find BAPIs implementation of handling return message quite inconsistent. Some BAPIs return a success message, some don't.

Ad Q2, Q3 Always call BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT or BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK after a BAPI call depending on result. BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT and BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK not only execute commit / rollback work but also call BUFFER_REFRESH_ALL function.